# Regular expression to replace string values

Tags: sql, regex, string, notepad++

I have bunch of SQL insert statements like this

```
Insert into CHANGE_PROPERTY (EXCHANGE_PROPERTY_ID, NAMR...) values(**'113'**,'ABC')
```

I need to replace the PK value(EXCHANGE_PROPERTY_ID column) with sequence. After that the above query will be

```
 Insert into CHANGE_PROPERTY (EXCHANGE_PROPERTY_ID, NAMR...) values(**SEQ.nextval**,'ABC')
```

Doing it manually will consume lot of time.I heard i can use regular expression in Notepad++ editor to do it but don't have any idea how to use it.

Can someone please tell me which regular expression to use?

Comment: I assume the `**` are mistakes.

Comment: yes..i didn't put it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `values\([^,]+` with `values(SEQ.nextval`.